# Por que el método no me recupera los datos del archivo binario la segunda vez que ejecuto el programa?

Tags: c++, c++17

El problema es que yo guardo los objetos de una clase y el metodo sirve de los mas bien, si trato de leerlos tambien me los lee muy bien, el problema viene cuando termina de ejecutarse el programa, la proxima vez que lo ejecuto y trato de cargar los datos guardados en el archivo binario no me funciona y me tira este error "Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)", y ya estoy pensando si es un problema del IDE Clion

```
void Archivos<tipo>::guarda(fstream& salida, string nombre, tipo* obj) {
    salida.open(nombre,ios::binary | ios::out);

    if(salida.is_open()) {
        salida.write((char *) &obj, sizeof(tipo));
    }
    cout << "Se ingresaron con exito" << endl;
    salida.close();
}

template<class tipo>
void Archivos<tipo>::leer(string nombre, fstream& salida) {
    tipo temp;
    int pos;

    salida.open(nombre, ios::binary | ios::in);
    
    while (!salida.eof()) {
        salida.read((char *) &temp, sizeof(temp));
        cout << temp.toString();
    }
    salida.close();
}
```

Comment: ¿Qué datos introduces? ¿has comprobado que el flujo de archivo `fstream` sea válido después de la operación `open`?

Comment: Te falta un template